# Why does the minimum eigenvalue sharply decrease when the number of basis functions increases from 37 to 38 and more?

Tags: numerical-integration, numerics, eigenvalues, numerical-value

I have the following Hamiltonian: **H = -1/2 * Laplacian -1/r - 2 * r/5 * (Exp[-r * 1.6] + Exp[-r * 3.1])**

I'm trying to find the minimum eigenvalue of this Hamiltonian using the matrix method. As basis functions, I use the functions of the 3D harmonic oscillator (l=0 for simplicity).

The basis functions: Psi[r_, n_] := (-1)^n E^(-1/2 r^2) Sqrt[2 n!/Gamma[n + 3/2]] LaguerreL[n, 1/2, r^2]; (3d harmonic oscillator functions (l=0))

When using 37 basis functions, the minimum eigenvalue is -0.573135. But as the number of basis functions increases, the minimum eigenvalue sharply decreases (38 basis functions - the minimum eigenvalue is -81.6894; 39 basis functions - the minimum eigenvalue is -1659.79, etc.). At the same time, it is known that with an increase in the number of basis functions, the eigenvalues should become more accurate, which clearly contradicts such abrupt changes.

Why is there such a sharp change in the values of the eigenvalues when going from 37 basis functions to a large number of basis functions?

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

(*number of basis functions*)
nmax = 37;

(*3d oscillator basis functions*)
Psi[r_, n_] := (-1)^n*Exp[-1/2*r^2]*Sqrt[2*n!/Gamma[n + 3/2]]*
   LaguerreL[n, 1/2, r^2];

(*kinetic energy*)
nmx = nmax;
hm = ConstantArray[0, {nmx + 1, nmx + 1}];
Do[hm[[1 + n1, 1 + n2]] = 
  KroneckerDelta[n1 - n2]*(n1 + 3/4) - 
   Sqrt[(2 (n1)^2 + (n1))/8] KroneckerDelta[n1 - n2 - 1];
 hm[[1 + n2, 1 + n1]] = hm[[1 + n1, 1 + n2]];, {n1, 0, nmx}, {n2, 0, 
  n1}]
KK = N[hm];

(*potential energy*)
VH[r_] := -(1/r) - 2*r/5*(Exp[-r*1.6] + Exp[-r*3.1])
Px[n1_, n2_] := 
  NIntegrate[
   Psi[r, n2]*FullSimplify[VH[r]]*Psi[r, n1]*r^2, {r, 0, \[Infinity]}];
PP = Table[Px[n1, n2], {n1, 0, nmax}, {n2, 0, nmax}];

(*energy*)
EE = KK + PP;

(*eigenvalues*)
Eeig = Sort[Eigenvalues[EE]]

Out[983]= {-0.573135, -0.236997, -0.0671774, 0.144736, 0.239897, \
0.523308, 1.00408, 1.52863, 2.00841, 2.44838, 3.1349, 3.92686, \
4.7779, 5.56374, 6.51545, 7.55435, 8.66113, 9.77227, 11.12, 12.4818, \
13.9725, 15.5607, 17.2093, 18.8041, 20.5845, 22.6299, 24.9144, \
27.1878, 29.6884, 32.0316, 34.8744, 37.786, 41.1211, 44.5046, \
48.5159, 52.6228, 58.0414, 63.613}

(*Energy in dimensionless units*)
Emin = Min[Eeig]

Out[984]= -0.573135 (*37 basis functions*)

(*-81.6894 - 38 basis functions, -1659.79 - 39 basis functions*)
```

Comment: When I try to run your code, I get an error that "NIntegrate failed to converge..." Perhaps erroneous integrations are causing the eigenvalues to act unexpectedly.

Comment: @bill s, yes, but error related to accuracy

Comment: If it were me, I would try to get reliable values from the integrations -- without them the eigenvalues are likely incorrect.

Comment: @bill s, the thing is, I don't really know how to make the error messages not appear.

Comment: Re integration warnings, take some specific `n1` and `n2` and analyze in detail why you get a warning. Take `Px[23,38]` for example. Plot the integrand to see what you are dealing with. Split the integral into `NIntegrate[...,{r,0,15}]` and `NIntegrate[...,{r,15,Infinity}]` for example, and compare to `NIntegrate[...,{r,0,Infinity}]`.  Then try different methods for the integration. Go to [the documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NIntegrate.html) and read about Options, Possible issues, ... Your `VH` has three terms, you could try to integrate separately 3 times.